# MSSQL merge with distributed transaction alternative

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a distributed transaction where I need to merge into the target remote table.
Now MERGE INTO isn't allowed according to MSDN: “target_table cannot be a remote table”.

So my workaround goes as follows: 0. begin distributed transaction 1. define a cursor 2. open it 3. if cursor has at least one record (CURSOR_STATUS()=1) fetch next 4. if exists (select top 1 * from target_remote_table where id = @myCurrentCursorId) -> when true update target_remote_table when false insert into target_remote_table 5. commit/rollback distributed transaction depending on trancount and xact_state

It works but I know that cursors are evil and you shouldn't use them. So I want to ask if there is any other way I could solve this by not using cursors?

```
USE [My_DB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[my_proc_merge_into_remote_table]
@ID_A INT, 
@ID_B INT

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- CURSOR VALUES
DECLARE @field_A INT
DECLARE @field_B INT
DECLARE @field_C INT
DECLARE @field_D BIT
DECLARE @field_E INT
DECLARE @field_F DATETIME
DECLARE @field_G VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @field_H DATETIME
DECLARE @field_I VARCHAR(20)


 BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION 

    -- CURSOR !!
    DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT      b.field_A , 
                b.field_B,
                c.field_C,
                a.field_D, 
                a.field_E,
                GETDATE() AS field_F,
                a.field_G, 
                GETDATE() AS field_H, 
                a.field_I
         FROM dbo.source_tbl a
         LEFT JOIN dbo.base_element_tbl l 
            ON a.obj_id = l.obj_id AND a.element_id = l.element_id 
         INNER JOIN dbo.base_obj_tbl b 
            ON a.obj_id = b.obj_id 
         INNER JOIN dbo.element_tbl c 
            ON a.element_id = c.element_id 
         WHERE a.ID_B = @ID_B
            AND a.ID_A = @ID_A;


    OPEN my_cursor;


    -- check if cursor result set has at least one row
    IF CURSOR_STATUS('global', 'my_cursor') = 1 BEGIN   

        FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor 
           INTO @field_A,
                @field_B,
                @field_C,
                @field_D,
                @field_E,
                @field_F,
                @field_G,
                @field_H,
                @field_I;


        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
            -- HINT: MY_REMOTE_TARGET_TABLE is a Synonym which already points to the correct database and table
            IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM MY_REMOTE_TARGET_TABLE WHERE field_A = @field_A AND field_B = @field_B AND field_C = @field_C AND field_E = @field_E)
                UPDATE MY_REMOTE_TARGET_TABLE SET field_D = @field_D, field_H = @field_H, field_I = @field_I;
            ELSE 
                INSERT INTO MY_REMOTE_TARGET_TABLE (field_A, field_B, field_C, field_D, field_E, field_F, field_G, field_H, field_I) VALUES (@field_A, @field_B, @field_C, @field_D, @field_E, @field_F, @field_G, @field_H, @field_I);

            FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor 
               INTO @field_A,
                    @field_B,
                    @field_C,
                    @field_D,
                    @field_E,
                    @field_F,
                    @field_G,
                    @field_H,
                    @field_I;

        END;
    END;

    CLOSE my_cursor;
    DEALLOCATE my_cursor;


    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0 AND XACT_STATE() = 1)
    BEGIN
        COMMIT TRANSACTION 
    END     


END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0 AND XACT_STATE() = -1)        
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

END CATCH;

END
```

Comment: Target of MERGE cannot be a remote table, but Source can. You can run your query from the remote server.

Comment: Also, anything that can be written with MERGE can also be rewritten with INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE combination

Comment: i will try to start the merge from within remote server. "also be rewritten with INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE" that's exactly what i did, it's just the part where you need to decide if we need an insert or update which is tricky. as of now i do this by selecting each record via the cursor and check one by one if it is already there. i was just wondering if there are better solutions than that on the host server. also the cursor solution is very slow, so that's another reason why.

Comment: Without looking at exact query I can't tell for sure, but you don't need to run INSERT/UPDATE on row-to-row basis. You should be able to update all rows that need updating with one single statement, and then insert all that need inserting with another statement. (INNER JOIN on target for update, LEFT JOIN + WHERE NULL for insert)

Comment: I added above what I have so far. How would I have to change this in order to do what you said?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, first inner join target and source to update, then left join to insert missing.

```
;WITH CTE_Source AS 
(   
    SELECT  b.field_A , 
            b.field_B,
            c.field_C,
            a.field_D, 
            a.field_E,
            GETDATE() AS field_F,
            a.field_G, 
            GETDATE() AS field_H, 
            a.field_I
         FROM dbo.source_tbl a
         LEFT JOIN dbo.base_element_tbl l 
            ON a.obj_id = l.obj_id AND a.element_id = l.element_id 
         INNER JOIN dbo.base_obj_tbl b 
            ON a.obj_id = b.obj_id 
         INNER JOIN dbo.element_tbl c 
            ON a.element_id = c.element_id 
         WHERE a.ID_B = @ID_B
            AND a.ID_A = @ID_A;
)
UPDATE trgt
SET trgt.field_D = src.field_D, trgt.field_H = src.field_H, trgt.field_I = src.field_I
FROM MY_REMOTE_TARGET_TABLE trgt
INNER JOIN CTE_Source src ON src.field_A = trgt.field_A AND src.field_B = trgt.field_B AND src.field_C = trgt.field_C AND src.field_E = trgt.field_E


;WITH CTE_Source AS 
(   
    SELECT  b.field_A , 
            b.field_B,
            c.field_C,
            a.field_D, 
            a.field_E,
            GETDATE() AS field_F,
            a.field_G, 
            GETDATE() AS field_H, 
            a.field_I
         FROM dbo.source_tbl a
         LEFT JOIN dbo.base_element_tbl l 
            ON a.obj_id = l.obj_id AND a.element_id = l.element_id 
         INNER JOIN dbo.base_obj_tbl b 
            ON a.obj_id = b.obj_id 
         INNER JOIN dbo.element_tbl c 
            ON a.element_id = c.element_id 
         WHERE a.ID_B = @ID_B
            AND a.ID_A = @ID_A;
)
INSERT INTO MY_REMOTE_TARGET_TABLE (field_A, field_B, field_C, field_D, field_E, field_F, field_G, field_H, field_I) 
SELECT field_A, field_B, field_C, field_D, field_E, field_F, field_G, field_H, field_I 
FROM CTE_Soure src
LEFT JOIN MY_REMOTE_TARGET_TABLE trgt ON src.field_A = trgt.field_A AND src.field_B = trgt.field_B AND src.field_C = trgt.field_C AND src.field_E = trgt.field_E
WHERE trgt.field_A IS NULL
```

Comment: thanks a lot for that! my mind was really stuck on this. cheers